# Bootstrap 5 upgrade some 'show' methods are not working

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have an old site recently updated to Bootstrap 5. The modals stopped working after the upgrade. They're opened with JavaScript, e.g.,

```
$('#myModal').modal({})
```

I can get it working this way:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Therefore the html of the modal is correct, including the css changes that were required. However, these ways of showing the modal do nothing:

```
$('#myModal').modal({})
$('#myModal').modal({show:true})
$('#myModal').modal()
```

I can reproduce this on my page with the example modal from the Bootstrap docs, but a purely clean page works.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, yes, debug bootstrap with the browser.

This reveals some porting is required.

The code is reaching line 315 in `bootstrap@5.3.0/js/source/modal.js`:

```
  // Static
  static jQueryInterface(config, relatedTarget) {
    return this.each(function () {
      const data = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(this, config)

      if (typeof config !== 'string') {
        return
      }
```

`config` is the options object. So it's not a string and the `jQueryInterface` returns after configuring a new modal, or finding the existing one.

If `options` is `'show'` then it continues to look up the `show()` function and calls it.

Also, `show` Boolean is no [longer listed as a member](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#options) of `options`, though neither is the `modal()` method.

Porting Choices:

- Specify `'show'` instead of empty options
- `$('#myModal').modal({}).show()` (to pass in options, doesn't have to be empty)
- Elminate the jQuery syntax and follow the documentation on making a modal with JavaScript.